# sending mail using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email

This is my send email function

```
public  function send_requs_mail()
  {


         $this->load->library('email');     


        $config=array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
         'smtp_host' =>'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
         'smtp_port' => 465,
         'smtp_user' => 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com',
     'smtp_pass' => 'yyyyyy'

       );


  $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
  $this->email->initialize($config);





   $this->email->from($this->input->post('from'), 'iftekhar');                    
   $this->email->to($this->input->post('to'));                                    
    $this->email->subject('Email Test');
   $this->email->message($this->input->post('message'));

  if($this->email->send())
  {
  echo'your email was sent.';
  }
       else
       {
       show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }


    }
```

Now when I press Send button I get successful message I mean I get message "your email was sent" but in email Inbox I didn't get any message.

Comment: Please hide your smtp credentials.

Comment: Have you tried to call print_debugger outside of the else? so that it prints anyways. Maybe it will show you some unkown information

Answer (score 0):

check if `$this->input->post('from')` and `$this->input->post('to')` return valid email addresses, otherwise it will not send the email!

Answer (score 0):

use this `$config` Array

```
$config = Array(
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'smtp_port' => 465,
'smtp_crypto' => 'ssl',
'smtp_user' => 'your mail',
'smtp_pass' => 'your password',
'mailtype'  => 'html', 
'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
```

);

And to install SSL
First see if there is open-ssl extension in your php.ini file if not then put the below code in the ini file in extension part.
extension=php_openssl.dll
Restart the Apache service.